# Graphic novel from 2014 or later with a time traveling device

Tags: story-identification, comics, time-travel, the-time-machine

I read this graphic novel two or three year ago at a Barnes and Noble. It was a newer comic—2014 or later, but not much earlier, I believe.

It centered around a man who makes a time traveling (interdimensional?) device, which is basically a giant rusty metal man, I believe, to try to save his beloved from the leader of these evil shadow creatures called morlochs/morlocks. It's set in an old -timey kind of world, kind of steam-punkish. I do believe however it is heavily based on parts of *The Time Machine* by H.G. Wells.

I believe he initially builds the giant metal man as some kind of attraction of some sort, and then maybe discovers some kind of mystical properties via alchemy/science/Native American lore. Other than that I'm not sure. I know that he has a crew of three maybe four other people who ride inside the giant metal man's head/chest and one of the is a Native American named "Hawk" or "Crow".

I also know that he somehow

> is the head evil morloch demon (you learn he's the reason or cause of all his problems with her)and he's stuck in this never ending
>  loop for messing with time or something like that.

Other than that, all I can recall of the cover or name, I believe it showed the inventor and the giant iron guy and maybe his crew. And for some reason I keep thinking that the name is like the iron Man or the iron fist or steel head or metal tophat ... something that has to do with metaI, but I HONESTLY don't know that for certain at all. Please help. thank you

I know that this sounds very similar to HG Wells *The Time Machine* graphic novel, but, it is not.

I THINK it was a one off and not part of a series but I'm not sure. Maybe the publisher was Dark Horse or Icon (nowhere near sure).

Comment: Hi, Brandon! Welcome to Stack Exchange. For some help improving your question, please see our guides: [How to ask a good story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) and [How to ask a good Western comics story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12588/102999) to help improve your question.

Comment: I'm just wondering what you think I missed? I answered all of those questions that I knew the answer to as best as I could. I suppose I could have said I THINK it was a one off and not part of a series but I'm not sure (hence the exclusion). And also I could have guessed at the publisher... Maybe dark horse or icon (once again nowhere near sure). Other than that I thought I did it right, what did i miss?

Comment: idk, I just always put that on questions :P just in case it reminds people of something. Anyway, your question is really good, hope you get an answer soon!

Comment: Thanks I've been searching for a while.

Answer (score 7):

It took me all day but I found it. I had read the first issue of this series in a preview a few years ago so when I saw your question I immediately recognized that I had seen the source material - but had no idea what it was called, where I had seen it, or how to find it.

[The Steam Man](https://www.darkhorse.com/Books/27-830/The-Steam-Man-TPB) 5-issue miniseries from 2015 by Dark Horse.

> Enormous steam-powered robots march across the Great Plains of the old
>   American West, protecting the populace against invading aliens and
>   monsters! The Steam Man and his operators seem to have their task well
>   in hand, until a crazed and powerful vampire comes to town intent on
>   bringing forth the apocalypse!

Cover art:

[image]

interior art:

[image]

The comic is based on a 1999 short story by Joe R. Lansdale

The antagonist, the 'Dark Rider', is...

> The traveler from HG Wells' *The Time Machine*.

at least in the story (which I haven't read).

You were right about the supporting cast:

[image]

Actually, just about every single thing you mentioned in your question was dead-on; it was just the content itself used such common terms that it was a huge pain to find.

For the record, the search term that finally yielded results, after I tried endless permutations throughout most of today was:

```
comic metal giant steampunk -hellboy -marvel -"iron giant"
```

..which turned up this gem as the 5th result:

[image]

..which contained the listing describing the comic you were looking for.

I am thrilled that I'll be able to sleep tonight.